# Converting list with dictionary inside to dictionary

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have looked on stack-overflow for an answer to this question (and beyond!). However most of them raised errors that, to fix, I would have to change the entire json. This probably is not the best way, but, what I did is get a json that is REALLY long. I then parsed the first time it and got this:
`[{'food': 'eat'}, {'food': 'eat out'}, {'food': 'go to dinner'}, {'food': 'go to lunch'}, {'food': 'go to breakfast'}, {'food': 'go out'}, {'food': 'eat out'}]`.
The only problem is that when I parse it the second time, it converts to a list. I have tried multiple ways of fixing this, but have found none that work. Here is an example of my code:

```
# location is location of json, called JoeLearn.json

with open(location) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
for checks in range(len(['food'])): # I will replace ['food'] with a variable with more data in it. 
    data['food']
    # Code to convert to list
```

After I do `data['food']` it looks like this (same as before):
`[{'food': 'eat'}, {'food': 'eat out'}, {'food': 'go to dinner'}, {'food': 'go to lunch'}, {'food': 'go to breakfast'}, {'food': 'go out'}, {'food': 'eat out'}]`.
How can I turn this into a dictionary so I can preform `.keys()` on it? If you have questions, please leave a comment. If you have an answer, please add it to the answers, as so many people leave answers in the comments.

Thanks in advance,
- User 9297446

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
with open(location) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
food_list = [x['food'] for x in data] #find all value that with 'food' as key
```

Comment: Yes this works. I am surprised I could not find this answer anywhere! Thanks!